# Removing values from a list in python

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have a large file of names and values on a single line separated by a space:

`name1 name2 name3....`

Following the long list of names is a list of values corresponding to the names. The values can be 0-4 or na. What I want to do is consolidate the data file and remove all the names and and values when the value is `na`.

For instance, the final line of name in this file is like so:

`namenexttolast nameonemore namethelast 0 na 2`

I would like the following output:

`namenexttolast namethelast 0 2`

How would I do this using Python?

Comment: I assume you have no control over the format the data comes in, but just in case you do, it would make your code much more elegant if you had names and values on separate lines.

Comment: The edit on this question is epic. Kudos to Wayne Werner for practically divine editing skill.

Comment: Why, thank you! I just can't stand poor communication, and if I can at least make out what they're asking then I'll go ahead and help. After all, nobody really benefits from a poorly worded/formatted question (or answer), and at least someone *might* benefit if the question is a little neater. Just doing my part for the SO community :)

Comment: It's too bad with your excellent communication skills you couldn't talk your way into keeping that vette...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Justin than using zip is a good idea. The problems is how to put the data into two different lists. Here is a proposal that should work ok.

```
reader = open('input.txt')
writer = open('output.txt', 'w')
names, nums = [], []
row = reader.read().split(' ')
x = len(row)/2
for (a, b) in [(n, v) for n, v in zip(row[:x], row[x:]) if v!='na']:
    names.append(a)
    nums.append(b)
writer.write(' '.join(names))
writer.write(' ')
writer.write(' '.join(nums))
#writer.write(' '.join(names+nums)) is nicer but cause list to be concat
```

Comment: I believe you will have to write a space between writing out your two lists, or your last name and your first value will run together.

Comment: @Jesse : Correct, Thanks. I saw your answer just before posting mine. It is very similar but I decided to post it. I didn't want to waste the few minutes I spent on it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you read the names into one list, then the values into another.  Once you have a `names` and `values` list, you can do something like:

```
result = [n for n, v in zip(names, values) if v != 'na']
```

`result` is now a list of all names whose value is not "na".

Comment: The OP asked for a string in the same format as the input, e.g. `n1 n2 n3 v1 v2 v3` where no `na` values occur. You only give the names of those users and are throwing away the values.

Comment: I believe this edit occurred after my answer.  By now, other answers have covered how to do this without discarding the values.

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "name1 name2 name3 v1 na v2"
s = s.split(' ')
names = s[:len(s)/2]
values = s[len(s)/2:]

names_and_values = zip(names, values)
names, values = [], []
[(names.append(n) or values.append(v)) for n, v in names_and_values if v != "na"]
names.extend(values)

print ' '.join(names)
```

**Update**

Minor improvement after suggestion from Paul. I'm sure the list comprehension is fairly unpythonic, as it leverages the fact that `list.append` returns `None`, so both `append` expressions will be evaluated and a list of `None` values will be constructed and immediately thrown away.

Comment: Storing names and values into a dict and then getting them back out using iteritems will not preserve order of the names.  (Not clear whether the OP cares about order or not, though.)  For that matter, `names_and_values` is already a list of name-value pairs, why create a dict just to get iteritems out of it?  Just iterate over `names_and_values`.

Comment: @Paul In response to your feedback, I've made a couple changes that you may or may not appreciate.

Comment: Yeeps! Did I inspire that? Oh, please don't get in the habit of using list comps as for-loop-one-liners. Better to learn `zip(*seq_of_seqs)` to perform a transpose on a sequence of sequences. But yes, I must admit this was clever.  Just DON'T EVER DO IT AGAIN! :)

Comment: Just to clarify: if I have `seq_of_seqs=[(n1,v1),(n2,v2),(n3,v3)]` then `zip(*seq_of_seqs)` will give `[(n1,n2,n3),(v1,v2,v3)]`.  I use this in my own submitted spaghetti code answer (or maybe it is more like tortellini code).

Comment: Yes, it's as if you called `zip((n1,v1), (n2,v2), (n3,v3))` etc.

Answer (score 1):

or say you have a string which you have read from a file. Let's call this string as "s"

```
words = filter(lambda x: x!="na", s.split())
```

should give you all the strings except for "na"

edit: the code above obviously doesn't do what you want it to do.

the one below should work though

```
d = s.split()
keys = d[:len(d)/2]
vals = d[len(d)/2:]
w = " ".join(map(lambda (k,v): (k + " " + v) if v!="na" else "", zip(keys, vals)))
print " ".join([" ".join(w.split()[::2]), " ".join(w.split()[1::2])])
```

Comment: Although quite difficult to read, I like your list iteration semantics. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
strlist = 'namenexttolast nameonemore namethelast 0 na 2'.split()
vals = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'na')
key_list = [s for s in strlist if s not in vals]
val_list = [s for s in strlist if s in vals]

#print [(key_list[i],v) for i, v in enumerate(val_list) if v != 'na']
filtered_keys = [key_list[i] for i, v in enumerate(val_list) if v != 'na']
filtered_vals = [v for v in val_list if v != 'na']

print filtered_keys + filtered_vals
```

If you'd rather group the vals, you could create a list of tuples instead (commented out line)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses just iterators plus a single buffer element, with no calls to len and no other intermediate lists created.  (In Python 3, just use `map` and `zip`, no need to import `imap` and `izip` from itertools.)

```
from itertools import izip, imap, ifilter

def iterStartingAt(cond, seq):
    it1,it2 = iter(seq),iter(seq)
    while not cond(it1.next()):
        it2.next()
    for item in it2:
        yield item

dataline = "namenexttolast nameonemore namethelast 0 na 2"
datalinelist = dataline.split()

valueset = set("0 1 2 3 4 na".split())

print " ".join(imap(" ".join, 
                    izip(*ifilter(lambda (n,v): v != 'na', 
                                  izip(iter(datalinelist), 
                                       iterStartingAt(lambda s: s in valueset, 
                                                      datalinelist))))))
```

Prints:

```
namenexttolast namethelast 0 2
```